# Communicate between Jenkins server without setting up master slave relation

Tags: jenkins

I would like to set up jenkins server that would run test scripts based on successful build deployments on other Jenkins servers. for example, if the QA jenkins server is named JQA1OnMachine1 and i have three others that are named
J2OnMachine2, J3OnMachine3, J4OnMachine4 (different jenkins server on different boxes) can the JQA1OnMachine1 (QA jenkis) poll the others at regular interval to see if a build was deployed successfully? if so can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins master slave along with [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/) Plugin would be one of the better ways to implement this however, since you don't want to use that approach you can explore [PSTools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pstools.aspx) to remotely capture processes or files on different server.

- Your builds may update a file on the build server post completion of the build and your QA machine can run script with PSTools to monitor and trigger the QA testing based on the file content